# Edit php line Smarty template engine

Tags: php, smarty

I want to edit my php template, but I can not get it right.
I use the the Smarty template engine.

My default php line looks like this:

```
{$childItem->getLabel()}
```

That does display HTML like this:

```
MY TEXT <br><span class="text-domain">TEXT</span>
```

I want to remove all content after the `<br>`. So that it only displays the `MY TEXT` part.

I tried this, but that does not work:

```
{$childItem->getLabel()|replace:'<br>' : ''}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: use `strip_tags` for remove all tags, and search when you get the text and fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use stristr function

```
{$childItem->getLabel()|stristr:'<br>' : true}
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot!! Is it also possible to use a reverse strstr? The MY TEXT part is displayed with a fist part that uses a " - " symbol. So is it possible to only display the content after the " - " symbol?